# How to detect global vs. link local IPv6 address

Tags: c++, c, ipv6

I am obtaining the address via the following code:

```
pcap_addr_t* addrs_ptr = device->addresses;
std::vector<std::string> deviceAddresses;

// Collect the device addresses into a string vector
while(addrs_ptr != nullptr)
{
    if(addrs_ptr->addr->sa_family == AF_INET) // IPv4
    {
        char address_string4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        struct sockaddr_in *sa_in = (struct sockaddr_in*)addrs_ptr->addr;

        struct in_addr i_a = sa_in->sin_addr;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(i_a), address_string4, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        deviceAddresses.push_back(address_string4);
    }
    else if(addrs_ptr->addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) // IPv6
    {
        char address_string6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        struct sockaddr_in6 *sa_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6*)addrs_ptr->addr;
        struct in6_addr i_a = sa_in6->sin6_addr;
        sa_in6->sin6_flowinfo
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(i_a), address_string6, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        deviceAddresses.push_back(address_string6);
    }
    addrs_ptr = addrs_ptr->next;
}
```

For IPv6 I obtain two addresses, one global and one link-local. How do I differentiate between the two in the code?

Comment: Global addressing is all in the `2000::/3` range, while link-local addressing is all in the `fe80::/10` range. Also, ULA is in the `fc00::/7` range, and multicast is in the `ff00::/8` range. Never use strings to try to figure out IP addressing (either IPv4 or IPv6) because IP addresses are unsigned integers (32 bits for IPv4 and 128 bits for IPv6) that do not break the networks neatly on the text representations. A network can break in the middle of your text representations.

Comment: @RonMaupin The string is for storing and later usage in creating a pcap filter that requires C string for compilation.

Comment: That's fine, but do not try to use strings for IP address manipulation or comparison because it can easily fail in a very bad way.

Comment: @RonMaupin So if I do a check with a string compare, all I need to do is check the first 4 characters to see if they are "fe80"? Do I need to care about the subnet denoted by "/10"?

Comment: Not yet, but possibly in the future. For example, a global address is currently in the `2000::/3` range. You cannot simply compare the `2000` in the first word to see if it is a global address because the current range is `2000::` to `3fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`, and that could be expanded into the future. Also, not all addresses in that range are globally forwardable. Other than global, ULA, link-local, and multicast (you can have multiple addresses of each type, except multicast, assigned to one interface) other addresses are generally invalid, but not all are.

Answer (score 3):

You may categorise IPv6 addresses by using the `IN6_IS_ADDR_*` set of macros.  In your case, you want `IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL`:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
...
struct in6_addr i_a = sa_in6->sin6_addr;
if(IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL(&i_a)) {
    addrs_ptr = addrs_ptr->next;
    continue;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The link local address starts with the bytes 'fe80'.